# All functions can be written as sum of product of $x$ and $y$?

Tags: functions

Can all functions of two variables ($x$ and $y$) be written as the sum of the products of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$?
E.g.

$a(x,y) = f(x)g(y) + h(x)i(y) + j(x)k(y) ...$

Comment: This is a very vague question. Are you allowing infinite series? Must the infinite series converge everywhere? Are you assuming that the function $a$ has some smoothness? As it is, the function $a(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad (x^2+y^2 < 1) \\ 0 \quad (x^2 + y^2 \ge 1) \end{cases}$ might be a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, infinite series would work as it would converge to the value of the original function at the point.

Comment: Also, uniqueness is required.

Comment: @JohnA. Are you looking for an unique expression for the wjhole domain?

Comment: Oh whoops, I forgot as I was about to do it after (answer can only be accepted after 10 mins). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let consider as counterexample $$f(x,y)=\log (x+y)$$

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample; however, I was thinking could an infinite series do the trick?

Comment: That function has a Taylor series about any point in the half plane $\{x+y > 0\}$, so it is not a counterexample.

Comment: @HansEngler but the OP is requesting for an unique espression and not different expressions, am I wrong?

Comment: @gimusi Where does the OP required uniqueness?

Comment: @HansEngler It is clear to me from the OP formulation, I ask a clarification on that.